# "No authenticationScheme was specified, and there was no DefaultChallengeScheme found." when sending request without cookie

Tags: asp.net, .net, cookies, asp.net-identity

I'm making webapp with cookie-based authentication. I have login screen, backend sends cookie and then browser sends cookie with each requests.

But when I try to reach secured endpoints (with or without cookie) instead of Unauthorized or OK, server returns Internal Server Error with this exception:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: No authenticationScheme was specified, and there was no DefaultChallengeScheme found. The default schemes can be set using either AddAuthentication(string defaultScheme) or AddAuthentication(Action<AuthenticationOptions> configureOptions).
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationService.ChallengeAsync(HttpContext context, String scheme, AuthenticationProperties properties)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.Policy.AuthorizationMiddlewareResultHandler.HandleAsync(RequestDelegate next, HttpContext context, AuthorizationPolicy policy, PolicyAuthorizationResult authorizeResult)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

My cookie authentication configuration looks like this:

```
            builder.Services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
            {
                options.Cookie.Name = "Testcookie";
                options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
                options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
                options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Lax;
                options.Cookie.Domain = "localhost";
                options.SlidingExpiration = true;
                options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(55);
                options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
            });

            builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            });
```

When I change cookie configuration to this:

```
            builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            });
```

Endpoints starts working when cookie is send, but have same 500 error with the same message when trying to reach endpoint without cookie.

When configuration looks like this:

```
            builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            });
```

I have 500 all the time.

Same result when I'm making calls from Postman or from Angular.

I totally don't understand what is going on, why I'm not getting Unauthorized from server? How this configuration should looks like, what I did wrong?

Answer (score 1):

To be honest i think the code should look something like the code bellow, not actually sure.

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme; //if you dont use Jwt i think you can just delete this line
            }).AddCookie(/*cookie=> you can add some options here*/);
```

if you don't use the Jwt token:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddCookie(/*cookie=> you can add some options here*/);
```

Comment: I've changed conviguration but nothing changes, sadly :( behaviour is still the same, don't know why

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the scheme as first parameter, something like the code below.

```cs
    services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddCookie(options =>
        {
            options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20);
            options.SlidingExpiration = true;
            options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Home/Forbidden";
            options.LoginPath = "/Identity/Account/Login";
        });
```

Also, make sure to enable your Authentication and Authorization.

```cs
    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();
```